# Alternate of JWS (java web start) in java 11

Tags: java

I'm confused about the status of Java Web Start. On Oracle's Support Roadmap we can read this:

Support of Deployment Technology

The web deployment technology, consisting of the Java Plugin and Web Start technologies, has a shorter support lifecycle. For major releases through Java SE 8, Oracle provides five (5) years of Premier Support for these technologies. Extended Support is not available for the deployment stack, and will not be available for support beyond Java SE 9. See the Oracle Lifetime Support Policy for details.

Deployment Technology for Java SE 6 and Java SE 7 may be removed at any time after Jun 2017.  Although the deployment stack may be included in Java SE 9 or later releases, Java SE 8 is the recommended and only supported version of the deployment stack.

Now, we have known for quite some time that applets and the Java Plugin were to be removed in a future version of Java, but I had never read about Java Web Start being a candidate for removal.

In Oracle's Java Platform, Standard Edition Deployment Guide#Getting Started (a Java 9 documentation page), Java Web Start is advertised as an alternative to the deprecated applet technology:

Although available and supported in JDK 9, the Applet API and the Java Plug-in are marked as deprecated in preparation for removal in a future release. Alternatives for applets and embedded JavaFX applications include Java Web Start and self-contained applications.

Am I worrying for nothing or I have missed an announcement about the deprecation of Java Web Start?

Comment: "I have missed an announcement about the deprecation of Java Web Start?" Yep, [you missed it](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/11-relnote-issues-5012449.html). Deprecated in 9, removed in 11

Comment: Specifically from the above: "The deployment stack, required for Applets and Web Start Applications, was deprecated in JDK 9 and has been removed in JDK 11." It's dead and gone - and this was announced some time ago.

Answer (score 0):

So far I only know about https://openwebstart.com/
The project was created exactly to fill the gap.